# php: shortcut to writing this?

Tags: php, shortcut

what would be the shortest way to write this?

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle)!==false){
    $len = strpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle);
}else{
    $len = 0;
}
```

I remember that I saw some shortcut somewhere for this that checked and set a variable at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$len = 0;
if(($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
    $len = $pos + strlen($needle);
}
```

I'd recommend against the ternary `?:` operator, even if it is shorter.

Comment: oh ($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false was what i was looking for. thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend against assignment in if evaluation clause too, even if it is shorter ;)

Comment: @Yuri For your information, this works because the assignment operation `$x = $y` yields the value of the assigned value (of `$y`) as the result of the whole expression. I.e. `($x = $y) == $y`. Hence you can compare the result of the whole expression immediately. :)

Comment: @Eineki True actually, but this is as short as possible without being really cruel. ;)

Comment: if(false !== $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle)) would be even shorter and still works fine

Comment: @Yuri You should learn Perl, you can probably do the whole thing in about 10 chars there. You won't be able to decipher it after a week, but at least it's short. ;)

Comment: also some reasoning why you are against ternary operator would be great

Comment: @deceze hahaha, i have been told that i should learn perl in the past. But instead i think ill learn python.

Comment: @Yuri Re ternary: Just because it's really bad for readability, as others here have said. Readability is much more important than the number of characters. Python may be a good exercise in this regard. :o)

Answer (score 2):

```
$len = strpos($haystack, $needle);
$len = ($len !== false) ? $len + strlen($needle) : 0;
```

Comment: very short! :D
also very good.
considering the function is extremely short and will never be looked at...

Comment: This is not the same as the above code. Consider the case where `strpos` returns `0` (Not `false`).

Comment: I agree, pretty nice, albeit bordering on obfuscation of intent. You may want to fix the evaluation part though, since `$len` may legitimately be `0`, in which case this code produces a bug.

Comment: @Yacoby, didn't see you comment there, that's what i also thought after some mins of looking at it.

Comment: Right, since php considers 0 to be false in conditional contexts the comparison to false is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$len=strpos($haystack, $needle);
if($len !== FALSE) {
    $len +=  strlen($needle);
}
```

and, in my opinion, ternary operator is terrible impact on readability.

Comment: What about the `0` default case?

Comment: @deceze PHP will cast it from FALSE later :)

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it, that totally depends on where and how `$len` is used next.

Comment: in my case its used in: return substr($haystack, $len);

Answer (score 0):

It is called the [tenary operator](http://php.codenewbie.com/articles/php/1480/The_Ternary_Operator-Page_1.html) and can be used like this:

```
$len = strpos($haystack, $needle) ? strpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle) : 0;
```

You should use it with care though, because it can make some expressions quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
$len = strpos($haystack, $needle) ? strpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle) : 0;
```

See also [Ternary Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
$len = strlen(preg_replace('/(.*?'.preg_quote($needle,'/').')?.*/', '$1', $haystack));
```

Probably slower and more memory-intensive, but it does require less typing.  So whether or not it's actually a shortcut depends on the definition.  It does present a valid option if you're allergic to ternary operators and assignment within evaluation conditions.

You could also do

```
$len = preg_match('/'.preg_quote($needle,'/').'()/', $haystack, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)? $m[1][1] : 0
```

although again it's a bit wasteful of resources to be using preg_ functions to search for fixed strings.